# The point to begin the plot from

Tags: matlab

I have a rather simple question. If I have a set of data A for the y axis with data from 0 to 100 in one column, and the same with the x-axis (time from 0 to 100), how can I plot the graph if I want to begin to plot the data from 20 to 100 (rather than 0 to 100)?

I hope that I made it clear. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [indexes](http://se.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) to point out a specific part of a vector or matrix.
Assuming that the x-data is in the first column of `A` and y-data in the 2nd.

```
startIdx = 20;
plot( A(startIdx:end, 1), A(startIdx:end, 2) );
```